# c# - Return color from a function

Tags: c#

I am making an application which will use function from another class, open color dialog and then return the color value to the form. I have written the class but I don't understand why it gives me an error. The error is

> Since 'Editing.ChooseColor' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.

My class code is

```
        public void ChooseColor()
    {
        ColorDialog ColorDialog = new ColorDialog();
        ColorDialog.ShowDialog();
        System.Drawing.Color Color = ColorDialog.Color;
        return Color;
    }
```

My form will call the function and the get the color value. Thanks for help.

Comment: change your return type from void to Color.

Comment: Change return type of function from `void` to `Color` and some searching online before positing would be smart

Comment: `void` means "my method doesn´t return anything". But you´re trying to return a `Color`, so you have to set the methods return-type appropriately.

Comment: Gliad Green I have spent hours searching that but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return `Color`:

```
// static: you don't want "this" in the method
public static Color ChooseColor() {
  // Do not forget to Dispose IDisposable
  using (ColorDialog ColorDialog = new ColorDialog()) {
    if (ColorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      return ColorDialog.Color; // user has selected color and clicked "OK"
    else
      // or other stub color (Color is struct, so we can't return null)
      return Color.Transparent; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ChooseColor()
{
    ColorDialog ColorDialog = new ColorDialog();
    ColorDialog.ShowDialog();
    System.Drawing.Color Color = ColorDialog.Color;
    return Color;
}
```

This is a public `void`, if you want it to return a color it should be a color.

```
public System.Drawing.Color ChooseColor()
{
    ColorDialog ColorDialog = new ColorDialog();
    ColorDialog.ShowDialog();
    System.Drawing.Color Color = ColorDialog.Color;
    return Color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`void` tells the compiler that the method doesn't return anything.  So trying to return something results in a compiler error.

Tell the compiler the type that you're returning:

```
public System.Drawing.Color ChooseColor()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed void into Color but forgot to write System.Drawing.Color or use System.Draving in my class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your function return a Color and only if the user clicked OK on the dialog:

```
public Color ChooseColor()
{
    ColorDialog ColorDialog = new ColorDialog();
    if(ColorDialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return ColorDialog.Color;
    }
    return Color.None;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. When I write Return color.none it gives an error saying that there is no None color. Probably change it to Transparent?